# How do I create a branch and how to use one branch in trunk in SVN?

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, rapidsvn

I have one php project which have two different branch and inside it some content is different. 
I want to create 2 branches for it in SVN but now question is how to use one branch in trunk?
If some files are common in both branches and want to commit data in both branches then how can I do it?
Is it possible to update some file in both branches or not?

Comment: Start from reading SVN Book about branching and merging

Comment: You should learn more  about branching and merging philosophy from SVN book.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add the most recent version to trunk and branch this. Then you can copy all data in this new branch and commit it. Then you can see all changes.

> Is it possible to update some file in both branches or not?

You can use `patch files` to apply changes to more then one branch (including tunk).

Comment: I created one project in SVN and added two branch in branches folder but now I am not getting how to set one branch in trunk?

Comment: When we do repo browser from svn then which URL have to set for it. If there is no any concept of branches then we set URL of truck folder while doing repo browser.